# If condition in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub NewRefesh()
    If Not Range("X2") = "COMPLETE" Or Range("X2") = "CANCELLED" Then
        Range("X2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=GetOrderStatus(RC[1])"
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code does for only X2 but i want do it till X52.

(Ex: Next check in X3 =  COMPLETE" Or Range("X3") = "CANCELLED" Then
        Range("X3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=GetOrderStatus(RC[1])"and do the action, next X4 and so on

Comment: have you tried any of the answers you got here?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your post you meant your criteria to be :

1. Not Range("X2") = "COMPLETE"  **>>** can be replaced also with Range("X2") <> "COMPLETE"
2. Not Range("X2") = "CANCELLED" **>>** can be replaced also with Range("X2") <> "CANCELLED"

**Note**: it's better to stay away from `Select` and `ActiveCell`, instead use referenced `Range`s. In your code you code directly use `Range("X" & i).FormulaR1C1`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewRefesh()

    Dim i As Long

    ' simple For loop, you can modify to find last row with data instead of 52
    For i = 2 To 52
        If (Not Range("X" & i).Value = "COMPLETE") And (Not Range("X" & i).Value = "CANCELLED") Then
            Range("X" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=GetOrderStatus(RC[1])"
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this one. Thank you. It's working fine.

Comment: @vaasusk  the please mark as answer (by clicking the v next to my answer

Comment: @vaasusk so you know how to mark as "Answer" - you need to click on the little **V** next to my post. If you want to keep getting assistance here, you should try to give some positive feedbacks

Answer (score 0):

use row/col numbering

x is Column number 24

```
for i = 2 to 52
If Not cells(i,24) = "COMPLETE" Or cells(i,24) = "CANCELLED" Then
        Range(i,24).Select
        Whatever you want done.........
    End If
Next i
```