# Passing cell values in user defined function in range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub PlaceOrd()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 52
        Range("Y" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=PlaceRegularOrder(Range("A" & i), Range("B" & i), ""BUY"", ""SL"", Range("W" & i), ""MIS"", Range("Q" & i), Range("Q" & i))"
    Next i
End Sub
```

The above code throws an Error "Expected:End of Statement". Please tell me how can I handle this. In the above code "A", "B", "W" and "Q" are columns. But If I  represent "A" as ""A"" then the code is showing no error but A B W and Q are taken as text. How to rectify this

My function (PlaceRegularOrder(....)) should be place in Y2, Y3..... Y52 using loop. Some Values to be taken from "A", "B", "W" and "Q". Please let me know how can I do that

Comment: really ? seriously ? please find the time to give feedback to previous question you posted here (and you took a large portion of the code from)  , Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342459/if-condition-in-for-loop

Comment: You seem to be confused about the meaning of `FormulaR1C1` -- such formulas don't refer to cells using things like `A1`, instead they use things like `R[1]C[1]`.

Comment: FYI, a better approach to `Range("Y" & i)` is `Range("Y2").Offset(i-1,0)` with `i=1..51`. It makes it much easier to change the top left cell value `Y2`  later. Also you are not doing string math to find the ranges. Additionally to act on multiple cells use `Range("Y2").Resize(51,1)` for example.

Comment: My function (PlaceRegularOrder(....)) should be place in Y2, Y3..... Y52. Values to be taken from "A", "B", "W" and "Q" using loop. Please let me know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is trying to create a string to be passed to the `FormulaR1C1` property.  You are making three mistakes:

1. You are not using double double-quotation marks when trying to store a double-quotation mark within the string.  (You seem to have done it in some places, but not others.)
2. You are expecting that Excel itself will be able to make sense of things like `Range("A2")`.
3. You are not using R1C1 notation for cells.

Your code needs to be:

```
Sub PlaceOrd()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 52
        Cells(i, "Y").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=PlaceRegularOrder(RC1, RC2, ""BUY"", ""SL"", RC23, ""MIS"", RC17, RC17)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

That can then be simplified to be:

```
Sub PlaceOrd()
    Range("Y2:Y52").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=PlaceRegularOrder(RC1, RC2, ""BUY"", ""SL"", RC23, ""MIS"", RC17, RC17)"
End Sub
```